# Package/tool for exporting data using R

Tags: r, regression, survey

I am trying to clean up some old code. My workflow had been some data-wrangling -> regressions -> plots.

Figured it would be easier to split the data into three files for each step. The problem is that when I split the data post-wrangling, something odd happens and I no longer get the same regression results.

Not sure what it is - when I run the regression on the data post-export, I do not get the same as for the results using the pre-export data. The difference is tiny - about .003 - .005 - but really confused about the changes in values.

I tried to export data from R using the `readr::write_csv()`, `write.csv()`, and even `data.table::fwrite()` functions - but when I do so, my data loses *something.*

Any packages or advice is welcomed. Running out of ideas here.

Comment: Please don't pull down your post like that. If you think you have found the answer, you can self-answer Or all together delete the post.

Comment: Why is this question closed?

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a csv file and reading back in probably does some numerical rounding. You can use `save()` to save one or more R objects in a binary format to a file and `load()` to later load it. This file will not be readable outside R, since it is binary, but it should be lossless. (Since this works with any object, you can even `save()` entire fitted models etc.)